# Flexbox horizontal scroll not working - why?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I want just 3 items centered along with horizontal scroll for remaining items, Also I want the centered item to get highlighted on scroll or tap. Here is what i want

[image]

I am using flexboxlayout manager and here is what i did

```
flexboxLayoutManager=new FlexboxLayoutManager(getContext());
flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);

recyclerView_stats_list.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

and in the adapter viewholder

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = itemView.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
            FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp =
                    (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
            flexboxLp.setFlexGrow(1.0f);
        }
```

If i change the flex direction from column to row it centeres my 3 items but then it starts to scroll vertically, I need that same but with horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a horizontal recyclerView, you can use this in your adapter

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp = 
(FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
flexboxLp.setFlexShrink(0.0f);
flexboxLp.setAlignSelf(AlignSelf.FLEX_END);
}
```

set your recyclerView with FlexLayoutManager like the following in your mainActivity

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(mContext);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.NOWRAP);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

once you have set the scrolling and spacing is fine. You can create a drawable file and set onClickListener in your adapter to highlight. Try looking for highlighting elements in recyclerView. Read about FlexLayout on github to get more information as to how you can restrict 3 elements on the screen. Would recommend creating a class ItemDecoration and adding it to your recyclerView